# Values in DropDowns not saving pre-existing values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an MVC 5 application that has a large number of dropdown lists on a certain page. When I first create the record, all the information is present. However, if I edit the record, even though the page shows the current valid information, once the record is saved, the information disappears. I debugged the post controller action, and it appears the IDs are being passed to the database, but I'm not sure what is happening here.

Here is my Model for the affected page.

```
[Table("facility.PlannerRequest")]
public class FacilityPlannerRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Work Type")]
    public int? WorktypeId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Requestor")]
    public int? RequestorId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Hardware Location")]
    public int? EquipmentLocationId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public int? HardwareModelId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    public string FreeManufacturer { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Series")]
    public string FreeSeries { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public string FreeHardwareModel { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cost Center")]
    public int? CostCenterId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cost Center")]
    public string FreeCostCenter { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "RDI/WLP")]
    public string RDIWLPNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Associated System")]
    public string AssociatedSystem { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Breaker Size")]
    public int? BreakerSize { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Number Of Poles")]
    public int? NumberOfPoles { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Connector Type")]
    public int? ConnectorId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Connector Location")]
    public int? ConnectorLocationId { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Work Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? WorkStartDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Work Comp Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? WorkCompletedDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date Entered")]
    public DateTime? EnteredDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Modified")]
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }

    public virtual FacilityRequestor Requestor { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityHardwareRequestDescription WorkType { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityLocation EquipmentLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual HardwareModel Model { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityCostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
    public virtual HardwareConnector Connector { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityLocation ConnectorLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityPlannerRequestStatus PlannerRequestStatus { get; set; }

    ShopDb db = new ShopDb();
    public virtual SelectList RequestorList
    {
        get
        {
            var activeRequestors = (from r in db.FacilityRequestors
                         where !r.Deleted
                         select r).OrderBy(f => f.FacilityEmployee.FirstName); 

            return new SelectList(activeRequestors, "Id", "FullName");
        }
    }
    public virtual SelectList WorkTypeList
    {
        get { return new SelectList(db.FacilityHardwareRequestDescriptions, "Id", "WorkType"); }
    }
    public virtual SelectList ConnectorList
    {
        get { return new SelectList(db.HardwareConnectors, "Id", "Type"); }
    }
    public virtual SelectList RequestStatusList
    {
        get { return new SelectList(db.FacilityPlannerRequestStatuses, "Id", "Status"); }
    }
}
```

The above model is used for the create process, for the edit view model, I use:

public class EditPlannerRequestViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

```
    [Display(Name = "Requestor")]
    public int? RequestorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Work Type")]
    public int? WorktypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Hardware Location")]
    public int? EquipmentLocationId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public int? HardwareModelId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    public string FreeManufacturer { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Series")]
    public string FreeSeries { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public string FreeHardwareModel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cost Center")]
    public int? CostCenterId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cost Center")]
    public string FreeCostCenter { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "RDI/WLP")]
    public string RDIWLPNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Associated System")]
    public string AssociatedSystem { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Breaker Size")]
    public int? BreakerSize { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number Of Poles")]
    public int? NumberOfPoles { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Connector Type")]
    public int? ConnectorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Connector Location")]
    public int? ConnectorLocationId { get; set; }

    public string Instructions { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Work Start Date")]
    public DateTime WorkStartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Work Comp Date")]
    public DateTime WorkCompletedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual FacilityRequestor Requestor { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityHardwareRequestDescription WorkType { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityLocation EquipmentLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual HardwareModel Model { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityCostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
    public virtual HardwareConnector Connector { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityLocation ConnectorLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityPlannerRequestStatus PlannerRequestStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual SelectList RequestorList { get; set; }
    public virtual SelectList WorkTypeList { get; set; }
    public virtual SelectList ConnectorList { get; set; }

}
```

For my controller, my two methods for edit are:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var facilityplannerrequest =
            Mapper.Map<FacilityPlannerRequest, EditPlannerRequestViewModel>(db.FacilityPlannerRequests.Find(id));
        if (facilityplannerrequest == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(facilityplannerrequest);
    }

    // POST: /PlannerRequests/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="Id,WorkTypeId,RequestorId,EquipmentLocationId,HardwareModelId,FreeManufacturer,FreeSeries,FreeHardwareModel,CostCenterId,FreeCostCenter,ClientName,RDIWLPNumber,AssociatedSystem,BreakerSize,NumberOfPoles,ConnectorId,ConnectorLocationId,Instructions,WorkStartDate,WorkCompletedDate")]EditPlannerRequestViewModel facilityplannerrequest)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var plannerRequest= db.FacilityPlannerRequests.Find(facilityplannerrequest.Id);

            Mapper.Map(facilityplannerrequest, plannerRequest);
            plannerRequest.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
            plannerRequest.StatusId = 1;
            db.Entry(plannerRequest).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(facilityplannerrequest);
    }
```

And I'm mapping the values using automapper:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<FacilityPlannerRequest, EditPlannerRequestViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<EditPlannerRequestViewModel, FacilityPlannerRequest>()
            .ForMember(t=> t.EnteredDate, s=> s.Ignore())
            .ForMember(t=>t.LastModified, s=> s.Ignore())
            .ForMember(t=>t.StatusId, s=> s.Ignore())
            .ForMember(t=>t.RequestStatusList,s=>s.Ignore());
```

**Edit**

Something of note, if I step through the code, line-by-line in the post method, I can see that `facilityplannerrequest` is getting the correct post data, when I step to the automapper line, everything is still correct on both. However, once I get passed the `db.Entry(plannerRequest).State=EntityState.Modified` line, my information is dropped, but only on lines that are foreign keys. If I drag the yellow arrow back to the top of the method and step through once more, it replaces the information that it had originally removed.

Comment: FYI: Using a view model and using `[Bind(Include="foo")]` are pretty much mutually exclusive. If you don't want to update certain properties, don't include them on your view model.

Comment: I was well aware, I simply added the bind to see if there was something strange going on.

Comment: It appears that it has something to do with AutoMapper. After removing the view model, it works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out what is happening has to do with the virtual members that are in my main model. Since these members are foreign keys and are being set by grabbing information directly from the database, they can't really be "set" by automapper. This is causing issues with the mapper retaining information. Once I adjusted my view to no longer use these members and subsequently removed them, everything seems to be operating as it should. These virtual members are:

```
public virtual FacilityRequestor Requestor { get; set; }
public virtual FacilityHardwareRequestDescription WorkType { get; set; }
public virtual FacilityLocation EquipmentLocation { get; set; }
public virtual FacilityCostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
public virtual HardwareConnector Connector { get; set; }
public virtual FacilityLocation ConnectorLocation { get; set; }
public virtual FacilityPlannerRequestStatus PlannerRequestStatus { get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your issue but you mentioned removing AutoMapper helped.  I had a similar issue with custom AutoMapper mapping using the ForMember function.  For some reason the information was being stored in some type of cache or config and would ignore any new mappings.  The Way I fixed it was to add `Mapper.Reset();` before any custom mapping where I ignore or set a mapping outside the standard. Hope this helps.